# Uniform parameters passing and typesafety with Java generics

Tags: java, generics, variadic-functions, type-safety

Since I often have to deal with randomization, I'd like to make a class which conveniently groups all of those functions that I usually need. Among others, I thought of a generic `fromPool()` function which, given a variable number of objects, returns randomly one of them. Of course I had to combine varargs and generics, which I just discovered could be a big taboo depending on the cases (and I suspect mine is one of those).
Here's the code:

```
abstract public class RandomGenerator {

    public static int fromRange(int min, int max) {

        return (int) (Math.random() * (max + 1 - min)) + min;
    }

    public static <T> T fromPool(T ... pool) {

        return pool[fromRange(0, pool.length - 1)];
    }
}
```

The problem is that I can of course pass to `fromPool()` objects of different kinds, making the return type extremely variable. So, for example, I can do something like this:

```
int n = (int) RandomGenerator.fromPool("String", 6);
```

Which will work until `fromPool()` doesn't return "String", then causing this exception to be thrown.

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: class
>   java.lang.String cannot be cast to class java.lang.Integer
>   (java.lang.String and java.lang.Integer are in module java.base of
>   loader 'bootstrap')   at Test.main(Test.java:109)

Here's what I was wondering:

1) Is this what the "Type safety: Potential heap pollution via varargs parameter pool" warning which appears when combining generics and varargs refers to? Is there something more to it?

2) Isn't there a way to limit the generics effect so that you couldn't pass objects that aren't in any way compatible to each other to the same function call? Basically some kind of automatic, transversal overloading (I feel like I'm asking for the moon)?

3) I had actually previously wrote a much less generic version of `fromPool()` which only dealt with Number objects.

```
public static <N extends Number> N fromPool(N ... pool) {

    return pool[fromRange(0, pool.length - 1)];
}
```

Contrary to what I initially believed, it ends this version is unsafe as well because while casting between primitive types doesn't create any problems, casting between the various wrapper classes is not possible, so causing once again ClassCastExceptions. Isn't there a way to tweak this version in order to make at least this one safe?

Thank you very much for your insight :)

Comment: I feel like the problem lies with the caller, not the function.  Why would you pass different types of variables into the same variadic function, and then cast it to only one of the types?

Comment: @NathanMerrill So do you think that it isn't that big of a problem and I should just ignore that such thing is possible? I thought that this kind of things should be source of concern no matter what. because relying on programmer's discipline can be dangerous. Was I wrong in thinking that?

Comment: You should ensure that your function doesn't throw an error.  But if the programmer decides to cast it *outside* of your function, that is completely out of your control, and out of your concern.

Comment: Okay then. What made me think that I should worry about this is that usually the compiler prevents these kinds of senseless casting (for example, I can't compile if a string is directly casted to a int), while this function makes possible to achieve such an error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try something like the one below.

```
RandomGenerator.<String>fromPool("String", "Something");
```

By doing so, you will be explicitly specifying the generic object type for that function call. And also you need not to cast your return value since the generic type is explicitly declared.

When you don't specify the generic object type it will be inferred as `java.lang.Object`.

Comment: Didn't know about this, thanks! But why isn't the type inference strongly recommend by the compiler? For example, when instantiating a class which uses generics (any collection for example), a warning pops-up suggesting to infer a type. Why doesn't it happen here?
Also, what about that "type safety warning". Should I ignore it?

Comment: Everything is Object in java. So, wherever we use generic type if you don’t explicitly specify the type it will be inferred as Object. The same applies to the method example you provided in the question. And about the warning, it is always recommend to explicitly specify the object type rather than ignoring. If you do ignore those you would end up having too many object casting in your code which in turn make your code more error prone.

Comment: I wasn't referring to the type inference warning, but to the "Type safety: Potential heap pollution via varargs parameter" which comes out every time varargs and generics are used together. Can I suppress that warning (@SafeVarargs) without being afraid of anything, as long as I infer the type when I use that function? Is it good practice to disregard that error? In other words, is my generic fromPool() function fundamentally flawed or is it acceptable?

Comment: Yes. As long as you infer the type when using that function it will do good. You can suppress the warning by annotating.